# Why it gives 403 error in strapi sometime?

Tags: strapi

Problem statement: In strapi sometimes it is giving 403 error while getting content manager What will be the issue?

System Information

- Strapi Version : Strapi 4
- Operating System : Windows
- Database : MySQL
- Node Version : 16.15.1
- NPM Version : 8.11.0

#strapi #strapi 4.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the endpoint is either public or your authenticating as a user with a role that has sufficient permissions.